# How to get the date format style of postgresql server using sql

Tags: postgresql

i have installed `PostgreSQL 9.2` server on `Windows` and the date format style is `dd/MM/yyyy`, How can i find the date style using `SQL` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Try This

> select setting from pg_settings where name='DateStyle'

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html):

```
SELECT current_setting('datestyle');
```

[Interpretation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) of its values:

> For historical reasons, this variable contains two independent components: the output format specification (`ISO`, `Postgres`, `SQL`, or `German`) and the input/output specification for year/month/day ordering (`DMY`, `MDY`, or `YMD`).